# Binding two properties in a ternary-like way

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to bind two properties next to each other, with punctuation, but also have a default value if one/both of those properties are empty?

IE:

`{{ store.openTime | date: 'MMM dd' }} - {{ store.closeTime | date: 'MMM dd' }}`

If that either of those properties are empty, display a string instead ('Closed').

I've done it with this plunkr, but the extra div with ng-show and .length is messy.
http://plnkr.co/edit/tob7am?p=preview

Comment: you did it good but if you do not want to write such a html code in your main pages then you can use directives as a template engine...

Comment: What do you find ugly about it?

Comment: You could also abstract out the view logic to a view model and bind it to the view, something like this.  http://plnkr.co/edit/xYecZDa0inZMRRp8Vq5q?p=preview This way you dont expose the display logic in your html, instead your controller takes care of the viewmodel.

Comment: @pixelbits it's just not very concise. Javascript has two ways to make things cleaner. Ternary operations, and the "||" operator when the first value is undefined/false. I'd MUCH prefer something that's more in line with that than a bunch more html (which is already bulky enough).